# PDFlib- Right-to-Left textflow

Tags: right-to-left, pdflib, textflow

I really need your help...

I use PDFlib-API and i want to write PDF right to left (like Hebrew, Arabic).

I found a way to do this, but it doesnt support text flow, it supports only in one line.

The code in this link:
http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/complex-scripts/starter-shaping/

I use class shaping (you can see it in the link), but the Parameter of textflow have to be false,

if i change it to true i get an error message:

PDFlib exception occurred:
[2582] fit_table: Bidirectional writing mode not supported in Textflow

How can I solve this?
or any idea how to write RTL with Textflow? (with PDFlib API)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a documented limitation in PDFlib 9 and there is now workaround. As you can see from the error message, or also within the PDFlib 9 Tutorial, chapter 6.4.4 "Bidirectional Formatting":

> Bidi processing is not currently supported for multi-line Textflows, but only for Textlines (i.e. single-line text output).

Comment: thanks!! i used textLine.. do you know if there is possible to crop the end of the line according the size of the textBox?

Comment: you can do this, when adding the option "boxsize" and the "fitmethod=clip"